# How to fix FireFly Fabconnect container start issue: "User credentials store creation failed. User credentials store path is empty"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

Sorry upfront for the long question. I wanted to make sure all the information was laid out for you.

I am having issues getting my FireFly Fabconnect container to be able to read/see/recognize my user credentials for my Fabric network. I have tried everything, so I am hoping someone here can help me. When I start the Fabconnect container, this error is outputted to the logs (and then the container terminates):

```
User credentials store creation failed. User credentials store path is empty
```

I have tried a variety of things with little luck. I know for a fact the path isn't empty, so I am not sure what the issue could be. Here are pertinent sections of the config files...hopefully someone can spot something and help me out (this is for a production env as well. I am not using the CLI):

**ccp.yaml:**

```
credentialStore:
    path: /etc/firefly/organizations/peerOrgs/Org1/users
    cryptoStore:
      path: /etc/firefly/organizations/peerOrgs/Org1/users
  cryptoconfig:
    path: /etc/firefly/organizations/peerOrgs/Org1/users
```

**fabconnect.yaml:**

```
http:
  port: 3000
rpc:
  useGatewayClient: true
  configpath: /fabconnect/ccp.yaml
```

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
volumes:
      - fabconnect_receipts_0:/fabconnect/receipts
      - fabconnect_events_0:/fabconnect/events
      - ./fabconnect.yaml:/fabconnect/fabconnect.yaml
      - ./ccp.yaml:/fabconnect/ccp.yaml
      - ../../../fabric-prod/_dockerTesting/organizations:/etc/firefly/organizations
      - ../../../fabric-prod/_dockerTesting/client:/etc/firefly/client
```

**Folders/files pulled from Fabric Org directory:**

```
afcranmer@LAPTOP-3KCE1D20:/mnt/c/Users/afcra/Documents/_WD/fabric-prod/_dockerTesting/organizations/peerOrgs/Org1/users/org1admin/msp$ ls
IssuerPublicKey  IssuerRevocationPublicKey  cacerts  config.yaml  keystore  signcerts  user
```

The only difference I can see is the folder structure that is created when running `fabric-ca-client enroll` is slightly different than the one that is created with the FireFly CLI or the Fabric samples test-network. Mine just has an MSP folder (shown above), but the test-network creates an MSP folder and a TLS folder with 3 certs in it. I don't think that should be an issue but I am not sure.

In regards to my underlying Fabric network, I followed the instructions shown in the "Deploying a production network" section of the Hyperledger Fabric documents. I am just user containers rather than the CLI to stand up stuff.

I have an the following Fabric coponents:

- TLS CA
- Org1 CA
- Orderer Node
- Org1 Peer Node

Any help at all would be appreciated. I have tried everything at this point. I am happy to provide more information if needed.

Answer (score 0):

This error generaly happens when the CCP file is incorrect

here is a working one (based on [firefly's](https://hyperledger.github.io/firefly/v1.2.0/tutorials/chains/fabric_test_network.html))

```
---
certificateAuthorities:
  org1.example.com:
    tlsCACerts:
      path: /root/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/ca.crt
    url: https://ca_org1:7054
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: org1.example.com
    registrar:
      enrollId: admin
      enrollSecret: adminpw
channels:
  mychannel:
    orderers:
      - fabric_orderer
    peers:
      fabric_peer:
        chaincodeQuery: true
        endorsingPeer: true
        eventSource: true
        ledgerQuery: true
client:
  BCCSP:
    security:
      default:
        provider: SW
      enabled: true
      hashAlgorithm: SHA2
      level: 256
      softVerify: true
  credentialStore:
    cryptoStore:
      path: /root/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp
    path: /root/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp
  cryptoconfig:
    path: /root/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp
  logging:
    level: info
  organization: org1.example.com
  tlsCerts:
    client:
      cert:
        path: /root/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/cert.pem
      key:
        path: /root/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/key_fil_here
orderers:
  fabric_orderer:
    tlsCACerts:
      path: /root/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/tlscacerts/tls-localhost-9054-ca-orderer.pem
    url: grpcs://orderer.example.com:7050
organizations:
  org1.example.com:
    certificateAuthorities:
      - org1.example.com
    cryptoPath: /tmp/msp
    mspid: Org1MSP
    peers:
      - fabric_peer
peers:
  fabric_peer:
    tlsCACerts:
      path: /root/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/tlscacerts/tls-localhost-7054-ca-org1.pem
    url: grpcs://peer0.org1.example.com:7051
version: 1.1.0
```